# Verbs to indicate animals walking?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, usage

What are the various verbs that can be used to indicate walking for animals?

Saying something like 老虎开始走向巴士 or 小猫在街上走着 sounds odd to me.

Comment: Well, why not consult a dictionary. Animals usually not only 'walk' on a smooth, even surface like humans, but also 'jump', 'climb', 'sneak', 'hop', etc. There is no translation of this in Chinese, but here's a comprehensive description of locomotion in animals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_locomotion Now it's only a matter of consulting a good dictionary.

Comment: jukuu:The cat couldn't see and the fox couldn't walk.
 猫的眼睛瞎了，而狐狸也不能走路了。

Comment: Grimm's fairy tale, Town Musicians of Bremen,当音乐家去 about 4 animals http://www.shuku.net/novels/foreign/gelin/gelin27.html( 一头驴、一条狗、一只猫、一只公鸡) contains 走 １１times

Answer (score 1):

Native Chinese speaker here.

No, we do not have many specific animal locomotion words in Chinese. You can very well say they 'walk'. 
But, when we want to sound learned or create variation, we do have more descriptive vocabularies for movements. These words are applicable to the movements of animals, human, as well as objects sometimes. I can give you some examples.

dash - 冲 (横冲直撞 can describe a wild person or animal running around frantically);

measured steps - 踱着方步 or 踱步 (can be used to describe the canter of a horse);

cat walk - 猫步;

横行 - it is the walk a proud person or a crab;

limping- 跛足而行，跛行;

潜行 - moving stealthily under water or in the dark;

滑行 - gliding on land or in the air;

扑 - jump of a tiger, lion, etc. (any predator)

三步并作两步，连滚带爬，上蹿下跳 are more complicated modes of movement.

Comment: (1) 'cat walk' is more than often applied to models on a stage in a fashion show. (2) while you can express that a cat (猫) runs/walks with 步, that verb is neither specific to cats, nor is the only verb to describe a cat moving.

Comment: the Chinese word '猫步’(cat walk) is exactly the same as the English. That is the walk of a fashion model. But we do say 猫迈着猫步to emphasize it is the cat coming.

Comment: And of course, cats can made all kinds of moves. None of the Chinese locomotion vocab is restricted to describe only one species. Do let me know if there is any specific pose your cat want to strike. I will try find a Chinese equivalent.